# Razor MVC doubts in a small sample program

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I just started studying MVC few days back. As far as I know, I did a small sample program. But some doubts I been facing. I am posting my doubts and code below. Please help me to understand it clearly.

Here I created four views and controller and a student class.

**StudentClass**

```
 public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewOne**

```
@model MyTestMVCApp.Models.Student
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ViewOne";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table style="border-color:Black;">
        <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Place</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>--</td><td>--</td><td>--</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<label>Enter Name : </label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { name = "name"});
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="btnStart" class="button" value="Start Filling Details" />
```

**ViewTwo.cshtml**

```
@model MyTestMVCApp.Models.Student
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ViewTwo";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table style="border-color:Black;">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Place</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.Name</td><td>@Model.Age</td><td>@Model.Place</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<label>Enter Age : </label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { name = "age" });
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="btnNext" class="button" value="Next" />
}
```

**ViewThree.cshtml**

```
@model MyTestMVCApp.Models.Student
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ViewThree";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table style="border-color:Black;">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Place</td></tr>
    <tr><td>@Model.Name</td><td>@Model.Age</td><td>@Model.Place</td></tr>
</table>

<label>Enter Age : </label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Place, new { name = "place" });
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="btnNext" class="button" value="Next" />
}
```

**ViewFour.cshtml**

```
@model MyTestMVCApp.Models.Student
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ViewFour";
}

@{
<table style="border-color:Black;">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Place</td></tr>
    <tr><td>@Model.Name</td><td>@Model.Age</td><td>@Model.Place</td></tr>
</table>
}
```

**MyViewController.cs**

```
public class MyViewController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult ViewOne()
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        return View(student);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewOne(Student student)
    {
        return View("ViewTwo", student);
        //return RedirectToAction("ViewTwo",student);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewTwo(Student student)
    {
        return View("ViewThree", student);
        //return RedirectToAction("ViewThree", student);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewThree(Student student)
    {
        return View("ViewFour", student);
    }
}
```

**My doubts**

**doubt 1**. On the button click in ViewTwo,

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewOne(Student student)
    {

   }
```

is debugging instead of ViewTwo's [HttpPost] actionresult.. Why ?

**doubt 2**. How can I pass the same instance of the student object I created in the ViewOne to all other Views , because my need is

On ViewOne, I get 'name' property of the student, then I pass the same object to ViewTwo.
On ViewTwo, I get 'age' property of the student, then I pass the same object to ViewThree.
On ViewThree, I get 'place' property of the student, then I pass the same object to ViewFour.

On ViewFour I display all the values of the student that I get through the above views.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question exactly?

Comment: I did the sample above. There is a button in the ViewTwo. But on clicking that button, ViewOne [HTTPPOST] function is executing... Why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are returning ViewTwo from ViewOne's post action.  When you do that you're still routing to the ViewOne action.  The code below will show in your address bar as ViewOne, even though you're returning ViewTwo.  Looks like you had the right idea at some point where you had a RedirectToAction call but you don't have an HttpGet for the ViewTwo action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewOne(Student student)
{
    return View("ViewTwo", student);
    //return RedirectToAction("ViewTwo",student);
}
```

Another option, and this would probably be useful for you since you're trying to pass your Student object, would be to use RedirectToRoute where you pass the Student name, id or some other identifying item, as a parameter in the route.  So the uri would end up looking something like this:  ../MyView/ViewTwo/Joe

Comment: Yes. i got it jeff. thankx. can u pls consider my doubt 2 ?. here in viewone i fill the student object with name, but whn i get the student objct in viewtwo httppost action, the name is null and only age is set.. at end in the viewfour, place only fill, name and age cleard.. y ? how can i keep all values ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling from `ViewOne`. if you want execute `ViewTwo` Action then use as below

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ViewTwo", "MyView", FormMethod.Post))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is the view definition that you have missed a small bit of logic.

the reason why you are hitting ViewOne on postback is because you are not setting the values the form it posting back to.

so in your `ViewOne.cshtml` and subsequent views you would need

```
@Html.BeginForm("ViewTwo","MyViewController")
{
 //View code
}
```

The HTML.BeginForm will render with the RouteData if you do not provide it in the call for begin form.